# Test image is loaded by Picasso with Espresso

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, functional-testing, uitest

I'm developing an android application and i'm trying to test one screen that shows a list of elements. The list is implemented using a RecyclerView and each item has a name (TextView) and an image (ImageView). 
For testing first element name, i use the next code:

```
private static int ANY_ELEMENT_POSITION = 0;

@Test
public void thatAnyElementTitleIsDisplayed() {
    givenBuildingActivity();

    whenNoAction();

    thenAnyElementTitleIsDisplayed();
}

private void givenBuildingActivity() {

}

private void whenNoAction() {

}

private void thenAnyElementTitleIsDisplayed() {
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.buildings_container)
            .atPositionOnView(ANY_ELEMENT_POSITION, R.id.building_title))
            .check(matches(withText("some name")));
}
```

That fragment of code is working. But now, im trying to test that the image of one item is loading and displaying at screen. 
First, I have an ImageMatcher that test an image resource is the same that is showed by an image view. But the problem is that the image is showed through Picasso library, so it's loaded asynchronously, then when i run the test, it doesnt work. The code i have is the next:

```
@Test
public void thatAnyElementImageIsDisplayed() {
    givenBuildingActivity();

    whenNoAction();

    thenAnyElementImageIsDisplayed();
}

private void thenAnyElementImageIsDisplayed() {
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.buildings_container)
            .atPositionOnView(ANY_ELEMENT_POSITION, R.id.building_image))
            .check(matches(withDrawable(R.drawable.building_placeholder)));
}
```

The DrawableMatcher is the next:

```
public class DrawableMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {

private final int expectedId;
private String resourceName;
static final int EMPTY = -1;
static final int ANY = -2;

DrawableMatcher(int expectedId) {
    super(View.class);
    this.expectedId = expectedId;
}

@Override
protected boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
    if (!(target instanceof ImageView)) {
        return false;
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) target;
    if (expectedId == EMPTY) {
        return imageView.getDrawable() == null;
    }
    if (expectedId == ANY) {
        return imageView.getDrawable() != null;
    }
    Resources resources = target.getContext().getResources();
    Drawable expectedDrawable = resources.getDrawable(expectedId);
    resourceName = resources.getResourceEntryName(expectedId);

    if (expectedDrawable == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(imageView.getDrawable());
    Bitmap otherBitmap = getBitmap(expectedDrawable);
    return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap);
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
    description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ");
    description.appendValue(expectedId);
    if (resourceName != null) {
        description.appendText("[");
        description.appendText(resourceName);
        description.appendText("]");
    }
}
```

}

To summarize, i think the main problem is the Picasso asynchronous image load. So, there is a way to do the test i want?

Thank you for the answers

Comment: Did you try to use SystemClock.sleep(...) to make sure it's a timing issue?

Comment: Sleep is always bringing flakiness and making test slower, so even if it works sometimes it is not reliable